# GIF specification unsigned definition

Tags: gif, animated-gif

In the GIF specification, here:

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

It refers to 'bytes', which I naturally assume are unsigned chars. If this is the case, what does it refer to when it says 'unsigned'? Unsigned... what? The precise definition is important as it lets me know how many bytes to read in.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Isn't it pretty clear from the picture that it's a 16-bit value?

Comment: @Kerrek: Only if you know that a box made of dash characters means a byte...

Comment: It wasn't to me. Hence clarification. (I just thought it was conceptual rather than accurate).

Comment: @Amnon: As you may reasonably have inferred from all those other boxes made of dash characters that are labelled "byte"... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"unsigned" in the specification refers to a 16-bit integer, with the least significant byte first.

It should probably be noted that in C, `unsigned` by itself is a synonym for `unsigned int`, and at the time the GIF specification was written, it was probably reasonable to assume that `int` on most machines was 16 bits, so it's not entirely unreasonable for them to not define the terms they were using.

Comment: Thank you. I would take it's an unsigned short (excuse my ignorance)?

Comment: I believe the meaning of unsigned short is implementation specific, but usually it is 16 bits. But note the endianess (byte order) issue for portability.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever the word "unsigned" is mentioned in the document, the adjacent diagram shows the number of bytes taken by it. Looks like it's always 2 bytes.

Notice also that the appendix mentions:

> Byte Ordering - Unless otherwise stated, multi-byte numeric fields are
>   ordered with the Least Significant Byte first.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.